# Use very much long NSAttributedString is safe(good or not)?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I has sqlite Database.It has html text. I read data and convert to NSAttributedString.I'm using UIPageViewController and get sub string per page from NSAttributedString for set UILabel. All works like charm. But i'm worrying about NSAttributedString length.Because it's size very long 400000 - 12000000. Use very long NSAttributedString is is good idea and application may not crashed ?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong. You shouldn't have a label with the text 12000000 characters long. Just use a web view and load the html right into it. Don't bother with attributed strings and labels

Comment: I'm using UIPageViewController and get sub string per page from NSAttributedString for set UILabel. Every label max characters count 1500

Comment: then you don't need to worry about having a long attributed string because you only use small strings. If you see that app memory has grown dangerously (which is not really likely I think) just release other cached strings and that's it